# How to get the state of checkbox so that i can update my database??#android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have created few checkboxex in my layout and i have to update the database depending on the state of checkboxes.... how can i do that ?below is code
   **DynamicActivity.java**

```
   package com.android.layout;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.*;

    public class DynamicActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            char[] save={'s','a','v','e'};

            db.open();        
            long id;
            for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
            id = db.insertRow("08241A05"+(i+10),1);

            }
            Cursor c=db.getAllRows();
            startManagingCursor(c);        
            c.moveToFirst();

            ScrollView sv=new ScrollView(this);
            TableLayout tl=new TableLayout(this);

            for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
                TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);

                TextView tv= new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_ROLLNO)));
                tv.setPadding(0, 1, 10, 1);
                tr.addView(tv);
                c.moveToNext();
                CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);//creation of checkboxes
                cb.setChecked(true);
                cb.setId(i+10);

                tr.addView(cb);

                tl.addView(tr);
            }
            Button saveButton=new Button(this);

            saveButton.setText(save,0,4);
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    update();
                }
            });
            tl.addView(saveButton);
            sv.addView(tl);
            setContentView(sv);

        }

        protected void update() {
              //i am trying get the vlaues here and update when save button is pressed              

        if(cb1.isChecked()){
            db.update("", 1);
        }
        else{db.update("",0);}

        db.close();
        }


                  }
```

i like to know what is the best method to retrive the status of all checkboxex in update method???

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb,
            boolean isChecked) {
              //do something here ...
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the status when the save button is clicked

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i=0; i<25; i++) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) DynamicActivity.this.findViewById(i+10);
            boolean isChecked = cb.isChecked();
            // save it here
        }
    }
 });
```